# How to find tag name in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a jQuery function that tells you the tag name of a given element?

Say I have an element that represents a `<tr>`. What function do I need to call to get `"tr"`?

I need this for debugging. Thanks.

Comment: I'll advice you to use firebug to look at objects and DOM, there is a lot of info in every object plus firebug is the ultimate debugging tool

Comment: Actually I'm using it but found it not too helpful to log an element wrapped inside a jQuery object since it has dozens of members.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be quite easy, just use the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method:

```
nativeElement.tagName;
```

or

```
jQueryElement.get(0).tagName;
```

Or for all cases:

```
$(element).get(0).tagName;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `<tr>` element, do:

```
var tagName = tr.tagName.toLowerCase();
```

If your `<tr>` element is wrapped in a jQuery object, do:

```
var tagName = tr.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for tag name

```
$('tr')[0].nodeName
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple JavaScript code will get you the tag name of any given element:

```
   document.getElementById("<element ID>").tagName
```

or

```
 //inside a method
  this.tagName
```